# Boolean Algebra proving algebraically simple

Tags: boolean-algebra

$$(X'+Y
)(X+Y')=XY+X'Y'$$

I am just wondering how these are equal, and what laws are used to get there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(X'+Y)(X+Y') = XX'+X'Y'+XY+YY' \\
\begin{array}{cl}
XX' = 0 & \text{by definition of negation} \\
YY' = 0 & \text{same}
\end{array} \\
$$
so
$$
(X'+Y)(X+Y') = XY+X'Y'
$$
In classical notation it looks like 
$$
(\neg x \vee y)\wedge(x \vee \neg y) = (\neg x \wedge x )\vee (\neg x \wedge \neg y) \vee (y \wedge x) \vee (y \wedge \neg y) = 0\vee (\neg x \wedge \neg y) \vee (x \wedge y)\vee 0 = \\
= (\neg x \wedge \neg y) \vee (x \wedge y)
$$